# Read offset of data in textfile using ftell

Tags: c

so I have a textfile with data stored in it. Now I wanna calculate the position of each data in it, so I used ftell the following way.

```
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &id) != EOF) {
            offset = ftell(fp);
        }
```

Now the problem is, with this code I get the position of the end of the data, so the beginning of the next data. How can I get always the begin of the data, so starting at 0?

Comment: First problem, you need to look up the return value from fscanf, it does NOT return EOF.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d%n", &id, &length) != EOF) {
    offset = ftell(fp) - length;
}
```

From `scanf()` linux manual

```
n      Nothing is expected; instead, the number of characters consumed thus far from the input is stored through the next pointer, which must be a pointer  to  int.
       This is not a conversion, although it can be suppressed with the * assignment-suppression character. The C standard says: "Execution of a %n directive does
       not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution" but the Corrigendum seems to contradict this. Probably it is wise not to make any
       assumptions on the effect of %n conversions on the return value.
```

Comment: Nice. (I never seem to remember the ´%n` format.) You could even make the current offset accumulative and do without the repeated calls to `ftell`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it the other way round:

```
do {
    offset = ftell(fp);
} while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &id) != EOF);
```